# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension in macOS

Tags: ruby, macos

I am getting error while running `bundle install`. This is on macOS 12.6 (Intel chip).

```
Installing pg_query 2.1.4 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

...

An error occurred while installing pg_query (2.1.4), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  pg_query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error, macOS 12.6 (intel i5). This helped me:

- run sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  and then xcode-select --install
- https://github.com/kyleconroy/sqlc/issues/1889
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93573/how-to-reinstall-xcode-command-line-tools

Answer (score 2):

Deleting xcode tools and reinstalling fixed the issue.